# Face API Attribute Emotion Gives Null Object Error

Tags: android, azure, null, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I am working with the Microsoft Face API to detect attributes of faces such as age, gender, and emotion. The following code is working for me: `faces[position].faceAttributes.age` and I am able to get the estimated age. *(`faces[]` is an array of the type `Face` )*

However, **when I try to get the probability that the face is happy, I am running into the following error:**

> Attempt to read from field 'double com.microsoft.projectoxford.face.contract.Emotion.happiness' on a null object reference.

This is how I am getting the probability that the person is **happy**:
    `faces[position].faceAttributes.emotion.happiness`

Similarly, when I try:  `faces[position].faceAttributes.emotion`, it returns `null`.

I know that `faces[position].faceAttributes` is not `null` because it works for other attributes like age and gender but I am unable to figure out why it is not working for emotions. Does anyone know why this is occurring and what I can do to get it to work?

---

### Update:

For those who are experiencing the same problem, in the `AsnycTask` where you are processing the faces, you must include the attributes you wish to detect otherwise it says that it is a null object reference when you refer to them later. Initially, I had `FaceServiceClient.FaceAttributeType.Smile` and that was why it was giving me an error when trying to determine emotions. The following code goes in the `doInBackground` method:

```
FaceServiceClient.FaceAttributeType[] faceAttr = new FaceServiceClient.FaceAttributeType[]{
    FaceServiceClient.FaceAttributeType.HeadPose,
    FaceServiceClient.FaceAttributeType.Age,
    FaceServiceClient.FaceAttributeType.Gender,
    FaceServiceClient.FaceAttributeType.Emotion,
    FaceServiceClient.FaceAttributeType.FacialHair
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are not asking for `emotion` attributes during your request. All these face attributes are optional, so the returned object will only contain the one you asked. For example with the following request:

```
POST https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect?returnFaceId=true&returnFaceLandmarks=false&returnFaceAttributes=age,gender HTTP/1.1
Host: westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
Content-Type: application/json
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••

{
    "url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/907936570342338560/qHCX1E2B_400x400.jpg"
}
```

I will got the following reply, where the JSON, when parsed, send an object with `null` for emotion

```
[{
  "faceId": "e97a0554-99a9-44f7-9de9-614ef6d8843b",
  "faceRectangle": {
    "top": 117,
    "left": 106,
    "width": 219,
    "height": 219
  },
  "faceAttributes": {
    "gender": "male",
    "age": 32.0
  }
}]
```

If I add `emotion` in the `returnFaceAttributes` of the request:

```
[{
  "faceId": "da7c416f-3eb4-4132-8b3e-e317daf58c7d",
  "faceRectangle": {
    "top": 117,
    "left": 106,
    "width": 219,
    "height": 219
  },
  "faceAttributes": {
    "gender": "male",
    "age": 32.0,
    "emotion": {
      "anger": 0.0,
      "contempt": 0.0,
      "disgust": 0.0,
      "fear": 0.0,
      "happiness": 1.0,
      "neutral": 0.0,
      "sadness": 0.0,
      "surprise": 0.0
    }
  }
}]
```

I don't know how you used the API (direct calling or using a package), but you should definitely have a look to these parameters of they are available at your level. If they are not, use directly the API (doc: https://westeurope.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/)

Comment: Thank you so much Nicolas! I hadn't realized that I wasn't processing the Emotion Attribute in the `AsnycTask` so now it is working. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello Nicolas. You seem to know about using the Microsoft Face API. I was successfully able to follow a tutorial in which I wrote some code in Visual Studio to create a person group, add people to it, provide pictures for the people, and then train the person group and I used Android Studio to identify the person and it works. However, I have been unable to find a tutorial which explains how to do all of it in Android because my ultimate goal is to make a Facial Recognition app. Would you be able to point me to a source where I can learn how to do it?

Comment: When I try the following code in Android:  `CreatePersonResult createPersonResult = faceServiceClient.createPerson(personGroupId, "Bob", "Hi");` in a try catch statement, it simply prints " " with a space. Do you know how I can create a Person in Android?